# Bytes.fromhex and int_to_byte implementation in Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, byte, sha256

I have a Python3 function which i need to code in Ruby , the function takes 3 arguments , 2 strings and 1 number , converts them into bytes and gets the SHA256 Digest.

Python code is as follows:

```py
number = 1
bytes_number = number.to_bytes(length=(8 + (number + (number < 0)).bit_length()) // 8, byteorder='big', signed=True) 
a = "a416985e694697e6ef8b4c0126a2e26e5491fd91257c6cb3d699350e3ab285ee"
b = "fc488dbb52f9d805e48e9289f9f0f80caa9c2713750508bdb3ab5c648d0b9579"
string_hash = hashlib.sha256(bytes.fromhex(a) + bytes.fromhex(b) +  bytes_number).hexdigest()
print(string_hash)
```

The output in Python3 is

```
1640fb7d038f3f782478e7414e65df11209860756c1464fa462b62d1ec3f9685
```

I have been trying to implement the same in Ruby but running into some issues :

```rb
require 'digest'
number = 1
a = "a416985e694697e6ef8b4c0126a2e26e5491fd91257c6cb3d699350e3ab285ee"
b = "fc488dbb52f9d805e48e9289f9f0f80caa9c2713750508bdb3ab5c648d0b9579"
hash   = Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(a + b + number.to_s)
print hash
```

But the hash is not correct in ruby, along with this i have tried few combinations of pack and unpack  in ruby but I am unable to find the correct hash.

**Update:**

I got the hex strings to bytes done properly using the following code along with this the number to byte works as well but the issue now ends up being the 0 padding , i created a function but it fails in some cases:

```
require 'digest'
number = 1
a = "a416985e694697e6ef8b4c0126a2e26e5491fd91257c6cb3d699350e3ab285ee"
b = "fc488dbb52f9d805e48e9289f9f0f80caa9c2713750508bdb3ab5c648d0b9579"
hash   = Digest::SHA256.hexdigest([a].pack("H*") + [b].pack("H*") + [add_pad(number.to_i.to_s(16))].pack("H*"))
print hash
```

The add_pad function:

```
def add_pad(num)
    if amount.length % 2 == 0
      "00" + num
    else
      "0" + num
    end
end
```

But this ends up failing in few cases, for example if the number is set to 100 , the hashes generated dont match up.

Comment: You have undefined variables. Please put together a [mre].

Comment: @MattDMo My bad , it has been updated

Comment: What does bytes_number print in your python code?

Comment: @ricks bytes number is the python3 int_to_bytes() function , and in case if the number = 1 , the bytes_number is `b'\x01' `, if its 100 (the problematic case) it is `b'd'` .